# SSIS 'Deploy' button disabled

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 and so SSDT for VS 2017 but then decided to go back to VS 2015 because of some other complication. I uninstalled SSDT for VS 2017 and installed SSDT for VS 2015. Now the Deploy button is disabled when I try to deploy my SSIS project. There are no messages saying why it's disabled. Not sure where to go from here. I tried to deploy the packages separately in SQL Server but because I have a project level parameter my packages uses so it's giving me an error.

[image]

Comment: Did you press the _Connect_ button?

Comment: Yes, that was it. I should of seen it.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened to me! It did not exist in the prior version and you didn't have to click it. Also the `Path` field is misleading - it looks like you've maybe already connected!